# Rounding to 2 decimal points a DataTable based NuGet package

Tags: c#, datatables, rounding

I'm using [ConsoleTableExt](https://github.com/minhhungit/ConsoleTableExt) to print a tabulated table. I wanted to round a few decimals to 2 points. The NuGet package is using `DataTable`. Currently, I'm using `.ToString(f2")`, but I read a post which states that it's a bad practice to do that in a DataTable. Any suggestions?

```cs
// Main()
var tableBuilder = ConsoleTableBuilder.From(backtest.ReportResults(backtestResults)).WithFormat(ConsoleTableBuilderFormat.Alternative);
    tableBuilder.ExportAndWriteLine();

public static DataTable ReportResults(List<BacktestResult> backtestResults)
{
    var table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Pair", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Trades", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Average Profit %", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Cumulative Profit %", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add($"Total Profit", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add($"Total Profit %", typeof(string));

    foreach (var pair in _backtestOptions.Pairs)
    {
        var results = backtestResults.Where(e => e.Pair.Equals(pair)).ToList();

        var trades = results.Count;
        var profitMean = results.Count > 0 ? results.Average(e => e.ProfitPercentage) : 0;
        var profitMeanPercentage = results.Count > 0 ? results.Average(e => e.ProfitPercentage) * 100 : 0;
        var profitSum = results.Sum(e => e.ProfitPercentage);
        var profitSumPercentage = results.Sum(e => e.ProfitPercentage) * 100;
        var profitTotalAbs = results.Sum(e => e.ProfitAbs);
        var profitTotal = results.Sum(e => e.ProfitAbs) / 1;
        var profitTotalPercentage = results.Sum(e => e.ProfitPercentage) * 100;
        table.Rows.Add(pair, trades, profitMeanPercentage.ToString("f2"), profitSumPercentage.ToString("f2"), profitTotalAbs.ToString("f8"),
            profitTotalPercentage.ToString("f2"));
    }

    return table;
}
```

Comment: `but I read a post which states that it's a bad practice to do that in a DataTable` link?

Comment: Do you want to store the data rounded, or store it full precision and round it for presentation/rendering?

Comment: I just want to display it as for the post I dont remember which one it was

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `Round` of `Math` for round value. `Round(double value, MidpointRounding mode)` where the second parameter specification for how to round value if it is midway between two other numbers.

Example:

```
decimal decimalVal = 123.456M;
Math.Round(decimalVal, 2);
```